# Firebase - Prevent user authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I need to prevent user authentication if their email isn't found in `allowedUsers`. It doesn't really affect the app, since all the actions will be performed on the `users` list, but it will be nice if the authentication doesn't happen.

```
loginWithGoogle() {
    const userDetails = this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider())
      .then(user => {
        console.log(user.user.uid);

        const queryObservable = this.db.list('/allowedUsers', {
          query: {
            orderByChild: 'email',
            equalTo: user.user.email,
          }
        }).subscribe(data => {

          if (data.length > 0) {

            const userObj = {
              admin: false,
              ...
              email: data[0].email,
              name: data[0].name,
              verified: false,
            };

            this.addUser(userObj, user.user.uid);

          }

        });

      });

    return userDetails;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to prevent a user from authenticating with Firebase Authentication. All they do when they authenticate is say "I am X Yz" and prove it.

What you *can* do however is prevent that they have access to you database. For example to only allow white-listed users read-access to your database:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "root.child('allowedUsers').child(auth.uid).exists()"
  }
}
```

Also see:

- [How to disable Signup in Firebase 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38357554/how-to-disable-signup-in-firebase-3-x/38357717#38357717)
- [Firebase Authentication State Change does not fire when user is disabled or deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38345085/firebase-authentication-state-change-does-not-fire-when-user-is-disabled-or-dele/38354484#38354484) (inverted version of your whitelist)

Comment: Makes sense. I'll just have a long list of users in the Authentication tab in Firebase. As I said in my question, this doesn't affect the app i'm working on, since they won't have their uid in the `users` list. Thank you for your answer!